# Match string against array with wildcards

Tags: php, arrays

If found several questions that address matching strings, which *might* contain wildcards, against an array. Or in other words, a replacement for `in_array` that supports wildcards.

What I'm looking for is the opposite, matching a filename against an array that *might* contain wildcards. Currently, I'm using this code:

```
function in_array_wc($string, $filters) {    

    foreach ($filters as $filter) {

        // Regex ain't cheap, do we need it?
        if (strpos($filter, "*") !== false) {
            $filter = str_replace( '\*', '.*?', preg_quote( $filter, '/' ) );
            preg_match( '/^' . $filter . '$/i', $string, $result );
            if ($result[0] !== null) {
                return true;
            }
        } else { // no wildcards
           if (in_array($string, $filters)) {
            return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
}    

$ignore_list = array('robots.txt', '*.png', 'something-*-else.*');
$file = "test.png";    

if (in_array_wc($file, $ignore_list)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The problem is, the matches are a bit unreliable, especially when there are o wildcards involved. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, maybe somebody has a better/more reliable function?

Comment: You noticed that your result is relieable on in which order your data is stored in the array? This array ('robots.txt', '*.png', 'something-*-else.*') returns false while this one ('*.png', 'robots.txt', 'something-*-else.*') returns true. The probleme why this function is unrelieable is because your function will stop in any case at the first iteration through the foreach loop because in any case you will return anything. And your return will stop the iteration!

Comment: As said, all you need to do is move the "return false" out of the foreach so that it will return false only if no element of the array matched against the tested string

Comment: Aah, too simple. Thanks for that much needed slap on the back of my head ^__^

Comment: Let me know if you think I should delete the post or wether you want to chip in on achievement points by posting an answer